# Loading instance variables form a file in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Here's some code:

```
import fs = require('fs');

export interface Answer {
  order: number,
  text: string
}

export class Config {
  responses:Answer[];
  timestamp_column: string;
  name_column: string

  fromJSONFile(fileName: string) {
    var fileString = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
    var parsedFile = JSON.parse(fileString.toString());
    this.responses = parsedFile.responses;
    this.timestamp_column = parsedFile.timestamp_column;
    this.name_column = parsedFile.name_column;
  }

  mapAnswerToNum(answer:string):number {
    for (var a of this.responses) {
      if (a.text == answer) { return a.order;}
    }
    throw new Error(`Invalid response string ${answer}`);
  }
}
```

It reads in this file:

```
{
  "responses": [
    { "value": 0, "text": "At a loss to explain it..."},
    { "value": 1, "text": "Have a vague sense..."},
    { "value": 2, "text": "Pretty good handle on it..."},
    { "value": 3, "text": "Confident that I understand it..."},
    { "value": 4, "text": "Feel pretty expert at it..."}
  ],
  "timestamp_column": "Timestamp",
  "name_column": "First Name"
}
```

Notice that I am copying each instance variable from it's corresponding JSON field, one by one, in fromJSONFile. Seems repetitive given that I take care to make sure that the class is structured precisely like the JSON file. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assign`

```
fromJSONFile(fileName: string) {
    var fileString = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
    var parsedFile = JSON.parse(fileString.toString());
    Object.assign(this,parsedFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... By the way, that method (or do we call them functions in JS?) is documented as ECMA2015. I am not sure whether that means that I can or cannot use it with Typescript and Node.